# WooCommerce - Tax Calculated Incorrectly?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, financial

I am running the latest WordPress with the latest WooCommerce, as of this writing.

I have one standard tax rule setup for 20%. This is UK VAT.

I have a product setup at £350. 20% of 350 should be 280.

```
20 x 350 / 100 = 70
```

However, on my product page AND checkout basket etc, the amount comes to: 291.67 (ex Tax). This should be 280. This is really wrong! So I'm not sure it's related to how I am coding the output of the product page, since I haven't touched the checkout template at all.

I am not sure if I have set something up incorrectly? Why am I getting such an odd number.

Some rules I have setup:

- Yes, I will enter prices inclusive of tax.
- Display prices during cart/checkout: Excluding tax.
- Shipping tax class: Shipping tax class based on cart items.

I really cannot work this one out.

**The tax setup:**

[image]

**The tax on the checkout:**

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mikey

Comment: Sorry, -1 here. It's really basic math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its correct, its *not*:

```
ExVAT = £350 - ((£350 / 100) * 20) = £280
```

as that's calculating off the price that already includes the VAT, rather its;

```
 20% / 100 = 0.2
 0.2 + 1   = 1.2

 £350 / 1.2 = £291.67
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully follow. Is this to do with a setting in WooCommerce, or programming error in the plugin? I want the VAT to be calculated FROM the price given. 350 is its price. 280 should be the price without VAT tax.

Comment: Well £350 ex VAT is £291.67 not £280; I.e. £280 + 20% is not £350 (its £336 - (280 + 20 * (280 / 100)) but £291.67 + 20% is £350

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But why would it work this way? Do you know of a way to adjust woocommerce settings so that they calculate tax from the final amount and not as an addition to a price without tax?

Comment: 'Fraid I don't know anything about that package

Comment: If VAT is 20% over £280, then the total is £336. If VAT is 25% over £280, then total is £350. You are calculating percentages wrong and WooCommerce is not the one at fault!

Comment: It's absolutely not correct. There's countless of issues reported on Github that WooCommerce tax calculations are wrong. They even confirm it. 
While i don't know the exact fix, check out these issues for possible solutions.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/25347
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/24619
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/24619